# What's the difference between AEM Assets and AEM DAM?

Tags: aem, dam, aem-6

What is AEM Assets? Is it not the OOTB installation? Is AEM DAM the same as AEM Assets? Is there AEM Assets installation that needs to be done seperately?

Comment: I don't think you have any such AEM Asset separate installation. its basically AEM DAM now called AEM Assets, where how much memory/features utilization is depends on the Assets licencing that you have purchased. **To ease installation and deployment, all AEM Applications and add-ons are delivered in one single package with all functionality included. This does not imply that you have permission to use all features in the package.**

Comment: Please go through the AEM documentation. It will help.

Answer (score 5):

AEM Assets is the marketing name for the DAM since AEM 6.0, there is no need to make further installation/operation to have it on your instance except if you are willing to use advanced Asset features like Dynamic Media in which case you'll need to follow [this procedure](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/integration/dynamic-media/enabling-dynamic-media.html) .

Even so, before using it in a production system you must check if your license is covering it, assets is sold separately.

One last note, there is an Adobe  Experience Cloud (AEC) core service called Asset too (confusing ;)), it's a cloud service that allows you sharing asset between Adobe services you have in your subscription, for instance Target.

Answer (score 3):

AEM Assets is a AEM Capability just like Sites, Livefyre, Communities etc. DAM is the interface for managing assets. Essentially they are same. AEM Assets usually comes packaged with the standard license but it can be removed or bought as a seperate product/capability.

Answer (score 3):

Every object like images, videos etc are called digital Assets. In AEM the platform (or interface) managing all these assets is called DAM or Digital Assets Management.

Answer (score 0):

`AEM` Assets are the objects that live in `AEM DAM`. There is no separation between two.

DAM is the system where you can create, update, delete, retrieve and process assets including **workflow, metadata, desktop application and all the rest of functionalities.**

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that can stem from your question.

1. The sales licensing model that Adobe uses to identify certain capabilities of the product.
2. The separation between the tool to manage digital Assets and the Assets themselves.

I will elaborate on my first assumption as the second is quite easy and covered here in other answers.

AEM Licensing identifies 3 levels of DAM at this point of time.

1. AEM Sites Assets (Media Library)
2. AEM Assets

The difference between Media Library and Assets is available here
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/assets/using/medialibrary.html

It boils to the following:

- Metadata and the manipulation of those extractions.
- All the libraries carrying the ".dam." namespace can be used only when Assets license is in place.
- Components that relate to the assets share.
- Some workflow steps related to assets.

There is another point, when you buy an Assets license you can install it on a separate server to the Sites server.

Hope this clears it up a bit

Answer (score 0):

In AEM, platform managing assets like images, videos, etc is called as DAM(Digital Assets Management)

Answer (score -1):

Asset: basically a binary with a MIME type.
DAM: Digital Asset Management, used to manage assets

Comment: Thank you, my question is is there any AEM Assets seperated like AEM Analytics.?

Comment: No, there is nothing more to it.